# Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<form class="hotels-filters">
  <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1" id="all" class="hotel-filter hotel-filter-reset hotel-filter-active">Reset filters</div>
  <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1" id="expensive-first" class="hotel-filter hotel-filter-dropdown">Expensive first</div>
  <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1" id="stars" class="hotel-filter hotel-filter-dropdown">Start from 2</div>
  <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1" id="min-rating" class="hotel-filter hotel-filter-dropdown">Not under 6</div>
  <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1" id="distance" class="hotel-filter hotel-filter-dropdown">Close to me</div>
  <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1" id="favorites" class="hotel-filter">Favorites</div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var filters = document.querySelectorAll('.hotel-filter');
for (var i = 0; i <= filters.length; i++) {
  filters[i].onclick = function(evt) {
    var clickedElementID = evt.target.id;
    setActiveFilter(clickedElementID);
  };
}
```

Browser highlights this part of code

```
= function(evt) {
```

and says me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined"

Comment: This appears to either be a trivial typo or an indicator that [you did not spend enough time debugging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/497418), either way it should be closed as [off-topic (#2)](/help/on-topic) as it will not likely help future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the for loop condition otherwise, on the last iteration it would be `undefined` since the index is out of range(maximum index is `filters.length - 1` and the last index would be `filters.length`). The error is throwing because in the last iteration you are trying to set `onclick` property on `undefined` which is not possible.

```
i < filters.length
```

Answer (score 0):

The iterator is reaching one number more than the number of elements. Here is the correct iteration 
    var filters = document.querySelectorAll('.hotel-filter');

```
    for (var i=0; i < filters.length; i++) {

      filters[i].onclick = function(evt) {
      var clickedElementID = evt.target.id;
      setActiveFilter(clickedElementID);
     };
     }
```